# Error in comet plot

Tags: matlab, plot, error-handling

Trying to run this code in matlab but i get the error:

> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
>
> Error in Orbit_run (line 33)
>       Fx(i+1)= Orbit_Forcex(x(i+1));

It seems like it can't get the information I want from Force source. Should I rephrase it instead?

Orbit_run.m

```
     clear all;

  global m;
  global kappa;
  global x;

  m=2.2e14;
  kappa= 39.5;

  x(1)=1.97;
  y(1)=0.00;
  vx(1)=0.50;
  vy(1)=0.816;

  r(1)=sqrt(x(1).*x(1)+y(1).*y(1));

  Fx(1)=kappa.*x(1).*m./(r(1).^3);
  Fy(1)=kappa.*y(1).*m./(r(1).^3);

  tau=0.01;

  t(1)=0;
  n=1000;

for i=1:n
t(i+1)=t(1)+i*tau;

x(i+1)=x(i)+tau.*vx(i)+tau.^2.*(1./(2.*m)).*Fx(i);
y(i+1)=y(i)+tau.*vy(i)+tau.^2.*(1./(2.*m)).*Fy(i); 

r=sqrt(x(i+1).^2+y(i+1).^2);

Fx(i+1)= Orbit_Forcex(x(i+1));
Fy(i+1)= Orbit_Forcey(y(i+1));

vx(i+1)=vx(i)+tau.*(Fx(i+1)+Fx(i))./(2.*m);
vy(i+1)=vy(i)+tau.*(Fy(i+1)+Fy(i))./(2.*m);

plot(x,y);
M(i) = getframe;

end


movie(M)
```

and Force:

Orbit_Forcey.m

```
function [ Force ] = Orbit_Forcey(y)


global m;
global kappa;
global r;

Force =-kappa.*y.*m(1./r).^2;

end
```

Orbit_Forcex.m

```
function [ Force ] = Orbit_Forcex(x)


global m;
global kappa;
global r;

Force =-kappa.*x.*m(1./r).^2;

end
```

Comment: What is the *full* error message? Also, think about your indices. What part of `x` are you trying to access in your last loop iteration?

Comment: @excaza 
>> Orbit_run
**In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Error in Orbit_run (line 33)
    Fx(i+1)= Orbit_Forcex(x(i+1));** 

X and Y is the Orbit force :)

Comment: Globals are A Bad Idea, unless you really need them (and you don't). Here, you're using x as a global and a function param, so it's not clear what's going on and/or intended there. I suggest you remove your globals, and pass m and kappa into each function.